# Authorize.net - Passing Variable in Simple Checkout

Tags: forms, post, e-commerce, credit-card, authorize.net

I'm using Authorize.net's simple checkout, and need a way to pass simple text onto the purchase.

So it's just a simple button, and we want some way for a referrer to show up.  With paypal we just appeneded it onto the item name.  But I can't now find any way to pass something onto Authorize.net

We really don't want to have to change everything over to SIM/AIM type system, as everything is already set up.  I was hoping there would be some way to pass something along (in the notes / Item name / Description... anything at all), to avoid having to scrap everything we have with simple buttons.

Edit: If there is no possible way to do this, then going from a hosted simple checkout button, what is the next easiest way to accomplish this.